# A sentence which I couldn't even separate which part is what

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

My sentence is from a philosophical book and it made me perplexed. Such that I wasn't even able to separate the parts of it. So, the sentence is:

> *Modern philosophy begins with Descartes, whose fundamental certainty is the existence of himself and his thoughts, from which the external world is to be inferred.*

By the way, I am also confused about "preposition + relative clause" structure which is used by the author in this book. If anyone could explain this to me I'd be grateful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might want to put the question about "prepostion + relative clause" subject in a separate question, with examples.

Comment: Yeah,I'm going to do it later on. Thanks for your answer, btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's separate the parts, and see what they mean:

**"Modern philosophy begins with Descartes.**"
Descartes' philosophy was revolutionary, and it started "modern" philosophy.

**"whose fundamental certainty is the existence of himself and his thoughts"**
"Whose" refers to Descartes. He is certain that his thoughts exist, and that he exists. This is expressed in the often-quoted phrase *"I think, therefore I am."*

***"from which the external world is to be inferred."***
He is certain that his thoughts exist and that he exists, and ***from that certainty*** he concludes that the rest of the world must exist as well.

Does that help?